# Split First Name and Last name from Combobox

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have the following `Edit_Click` function and it errors on the `string lname = Strings.Trim...` line. It says that the name `Strings` does not exist in the current context. What am I missing?

```
private void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] fullname = ComboBox1.Text.Split(',');
    string lname = Strings.Trim(fullname[0]);
    string fname = Strings.Trim(fullname[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= CustomerList.count - 1; i++)
    {
        Customers c = CustomerList(i);
        if (c.last == lname & c.first == fname)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = lname;
            TextBox2.Text = fname;
            CurrentIndx = i;
            CurrentCustomer = c;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fullname[0].Trim();` not `Strings.Trim(fullname[0]);`

Comment: If it were a class method, it would be `String`, not `Strings`. But, as Loocid points out, it's an object method.

Answer (score 0):

As Loocid and paxdiablo point out in the comments, if the method were static it would be on `String` as opposed to `Strings`.

Because [`Trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an instance method, you need to call it on your `string` object:

```
string lname = fullname[0].Trim();
string fname = fullname[1].Trim();
```

---

Your next issue is this line (although this may have been a typo in writing your question):

```
Customers c = CustomerList(i);
```

It should read like this:

```
Customers c = CustomerList[i];
```

---

As a side note, you might also want to check the `Length` property of `fullname`. If a user enters "Test", you will only have 1 entry, so your code will fail with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Answer (score 0):

error `Strings` "does not exist in the current context"
means the Object you are trying use it not exists. you can use Trim on the `fname` and `lname` because it's an extention method.

```
string lname = fullname[0].Trim();
string fname = fullname[1].Trim();
```